# Is 3-way partitioning Quick sort stable?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am a middle school student from Korea.

I know 2-way partitioning quick sort [is not stable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13498213/quicksort-algorithm-stability).

How about [3-way quick sort](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3-way-quicksort-dutch-national-flag/)? Is that a stable sorting algorithm?

Answer (score 1):

No, 3-way quick sort is also not stable.

For instance, if `arr[i]>pivot and arr[j]<pivot`, then these values will be swapped, and the next comparison will be with `arr[i+1]` and `arr[j-1]`. Now if `arr[i]==arr[i+1]`, then we find that after the swaps, the order of these two values has been reversed.

The 3-way algorithm only deals differently with values that are *equal* to the pivot, but for values that are different from the pivot (like in the above example), the algorithm remains the same, and thus this algorithm does not provide a stable sort.

Comment: Sincerely thank you for your explanation!! It is very easy to understand!